# Rails Email Preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an application that sends invoices as emails. I'm using ActionMailer and Gmail.

I would like to be able to view those emails on-screen inside the production application.  So, I'm not looking for a development environment capture of email.  I want the ability to view the email before you send it.  Or look at it on-screen at a later date.

I'm looking at these email gems.  But, they seem to be written to TEST emails.

ryanb/letter_opener

37signals/mail_view

MailCatcher

glebm/rails_email_preview

I would appreciate any advice you have - thanks!

UPDATE1

The email is = invoice_mailer/invoice_email.html.erb Could that be displayed as a partial in another view?

This didn't work:

```
<%= render :partial => invoice_mailer/invoice_email' %>
```

I get:

```
Missing partial invoice_mailer/invoice_email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails expects view partials' filenames to start with an underscore, so if your filename was `invoice_mailer/_invoice_email.html.erb` then `render :partial => 'invoice_mailer/invoice_email'` would work.

What if your `invoice_email.html.erb` just does a `render :partial` of a file whose name starts with an underscore? Then I think your normal view should be able to use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

How is the content of the email generated? Couldn't you make a view incorporating that same content?

Comment: The email is = invoice_mailer/invoice_email.html.erb  Could that be displayed as a partial in another view?  `<%= render :partial => 'invoice_mailer/invoice_email.html' %>`